# Scrollable element with flex pushing other elements out as it grows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a page with the following layout:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                       |
|                           nav                         |
|                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                       |
|         content that should not scroll (fixed)        |
|                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                       |
|                                                       |
|                    Scrollable content                 |
|                taking up remaining height             |
|                                                       |
|                                                       |
|                                                       |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Since the scrollable content needs to take up 'remaining height', I decided to try and use `display: flex` to try and solve this.

I added the following class to all elements from the scrollable content up to the first element (`#app`):

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

The scrollable element itself has the additional `overflow-y: auto;` CSS property.

The top `#app` element has the following properties, most importantly, the height.

```
#app {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

With this setup, I find that as the scrollable content grows, the `nav` and `fixed` content start to get pushed up further and further.

What is causing this and how can I prevent this? I simply want a page with some fixed content and an element that takes up the remaining height.
Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/gurupras/pen/dQVPjL) of my page

Comment: Set the height to `100vh` rather than 100%

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to have any effect (still causes the same issue).

Comment: Show us demo of what you have so far

Comment: The last line of my question has a codepen of what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, with your approach of having everything in flex containers, using `display: fixed` on the navbar is doing more harm than good, since only the last div will be scrollable by itself, the navbar will stay in place regardless of the scroll. Once the navbar is `display: block`, then it is no longer taken out of regular layout context and its parent flex container can take its height into regular calculations.
Additionally, by default, flex children have a value of `flex-shrink` set to 1, which means that the height of your `tabs` container will shrink once the total height of all flex children will exceed the height of flex container. Setting it to 0 prevents that problem.
The end result with all the above fixes can be found in the forked [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QJqyvE).

Comment: I didn't realize that the shrink property on the tabs was what was causing the elements to get pushed/'shrunk'. This works flawlessly. Thank you so much!